# Two scanf statements inside a while loop not reading properly

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, scanf

First post here. I've been trying to write a very simple Knock Knock joke. It goes as follows:

Knock! Knock!

[user input]

Banana!

[user input]

Knock! Knock!

[user input]

Banana!

[user input]

... So on and so forth.
It's a never ending joke.
My problem comes from the scanf statements inside the while loop. If I type in 'a' for the first input nothing happens. If I then type ' a' (space in front), it comes up with Banana! If I type in 'a' for Banana!, it will continue the joke correctly.

However, if I type in "whos there" for the Knock! Knock! prompt it will go on to Banana! correctly; however, if I type in "banana who" for the Banana! prompt, if ends up saying "Knock! Knock!" and immediately "Banana!" not allowing input for the "Knock! Knock!" prompt the second time through the loop.

Here's a picture of those inputs:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgnny.png)

Am I missing something? I've tried adding getchar() statements. I've tried fflush(stdin). I've tried making the scanf a funtion and even adding a getchar() to that function. I've changed scanf("%s") to scanf("%s\n"), that helped but still doesn't function properly. It appears as though the second scanf is trying to take the whitespace as a terminating character and continue from there, but I am at a loss. I just want to make a simple never ending Knock Knock joke.

Am I just an idiot? 
What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    while(1)
    {
        //Begin Joke
        printf("Knock! Knock!\n");
        scanf(" %s\n");                 //Who's there?

        //Second Part of Joke
        printf("Banana!\n");
        scanf(" %s\n");                 //Banana who?
    }
}
```

~Knob

Comment: I know the solution, avoid `scanf()` completely. Use `fgets()`.

Comment: `scanf` is a bad idea if you want to read an entire line (`%s` normally stops reading once it encounters any kind of whitespace). Try `fgets`.

Comment: Or loop through `fgetc` until you hit `'\n'`.

Comment: I know scanf is bad, but shouldn't it still work. And if it's true that it stops reading once it hits white space, why does the first input not proceed until the return key AFTER a space?

Comment: Not if the response contains a `space`, which also is whitespace. For that reason alone, `scanf()` is not useful to you.

Comment: Uhm from cplusplus.com: The additional arguments should point to already allocated objects of the type specified by their corresponding format specifier within the format string. So why are you not providing an argument for the %s?

Answer (score 4):

`%s` is not a good idea if you want to read entire lines; it'll normally break on any whitespace character. Some dirty hacks exist to circumvent this, but I suggest you just use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LEN 200

int main(void)
{
    char buf[MAX_LINE_LEN];

    while (1)
    {
        //Begin Joke
        printf("Knock! Knock!\n");
        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);     //Who's there?

                                            //Second Part of Joke
        printf("Banana!\n");
        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);     //Banana who?
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Note that what you were doing in your code (`scanf(" %s\n");`) is *undefined behavior* - `%s` requires a valid `char` buffer (of sufficient length!), but you were providing none. In general `scanf` is best avoided due to its poor error handling capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

2 main problems: No place to save input and `"\n"` after `"%s"`.

Use `fgets()` instead.

---

Let us tear `scanf(" %s\n");` apart:

A. The `" "` directs `scanf()` to read and consume optional white-space (tabs, space, `'\n'`, etc.).   This continues until non-white-space is found.  That `char` is put back into `stdin`.

B. `"%s"` directs `scanf()` to 1) read and consume optional white-space 2) read and save endless amounts of non-white-space in to **oops** a missing character array.  3) Upon encountering a white-space, put that `char` back into `stdin`, append a null character to **oops** a missing character array.

C. The `"\n"` directs `scanf()` to read and consume optional white-space (tabs, space, `'\n'`, etc.).   This continues until non-white-space is found.  That `char` is put back into `stdin`.  (Just like step A.)

So 1) we have **undefined behavior** because there is no character array to save data.  2) Even with a character array like below, **`scanf()` does not return until non-white-space is entered (see step C.) after the the first run of non-white-space**.  Since `stdin` is *line* buffered, keyboard input occurs a *line* at a time.  That 2nd word will not be seen by the first `scanf()` until 2 lines are entered.

```
char buf[100];
scanf(" %s\n", buf);  // better, but still not so good
```

If anything code *could* have been the below, but even that has issues as it does not consume a *line* of input.

```
char buf[100];
if (scanf("%99s", buf) != 1) Handle_Error();  // better
```

Instead use `fgets()`

```
char buf[100];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) Handle_Error();  // best

// lop off potential trailing \n if desired
buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';
```

Comment: I understand that I should be using `fgets()`. Also thank you for clarifying that `scanf()` "does not return until non-white-space is entered" I just seem to be lacking the knowledge as to why using two `scanf()` statements in a loop will not work.

Comment: @itsknob The primary problem is _not_ all the fault of `scanf()`.  It is the format used.  That pesky `'\n'` does not let `scanf()` return until a following word (non-white-space) is entered.  When the 2nd `scanf()` is called, it consumes the that 2nd word, but it too does not return until a 3rd word is entered and so on ....  At the "end-of-all-things", avoid `scanf()` like the plague.

Answer (score -2):

From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/):

> The additional arguments should point to already allocated objects of the type specified by their corresponding format specifier within the format string.

So provide it with an argument:

```
while (1)
{
    char buffer[255];
    //Begin Joke
    printf("Knock! Knock!\n");
    scanf(" %s\n", buffer);                 //Who's there?

                                    //Second Part of Joke
    printf("Banana!\n");
    scanf(" %s\n", buffer);                 //Banana who?
}
```

Please note:

This function is unsafe and like already mentioned may break. Again consider using `fgets`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question; attempting to enter more than one word (where "word" is a string of non-whitespace characters) will not work.

Comment: @szczurcio Even entering 1 word will not work.  The trailing `'\n'` will prevent `scanf()` from returning until non-white-space is entered after the first word.

Comment: OP asked in comment what to do to make it work with scanf: "I know scanf is bad, but shouldn't it still work. And if it's true that it stops reading once it hits white space, why does the first input not proceed until the return key AFTER a space?". I tested this under Windows 10 Pro, compiled with Visual Studio 2015 and it works fine even though `buffer` is never used. And I already put credit to you guys for providing answers on optional ways to do it.

Comment: @Neijwiert Thank you for bringing this up. I'm not crazy, right? It _should_ be able to work. I understand that sending a string to no buffer causes undefined behavior. Is it that undefined behavior that is causing the second `scanf` to break? If it is, that would put my mind at ease.
I originally has `scanf("%s");` followed by `getchar()` which would have eaten the newline characters, however, that failed as well. I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.
Thank you for clearing it up a little bit.

Comment: Yes, It's likely caused by the `undefined behaviour`.